# Java Color creation throws IllegalArgumentException when used with integer arguments

Tags: java, spring, exception, colors

The following code when executed on *certain machines* in our company causes an `IllegalArgumentException` to be thrown:

```
Color sludge = new Color(133, 133, 78);
//throws IAE with message "Color parameter outside of expected range: Red Green Blue"
```

An equivalent call using **`float`** arguments instead *works*:

```
Color sludge = new Color(0.522, 0.522, 0.306); // 133/255 = 0.522, 78/255 = 0.306
```

Why might this be the case? And why would it only affect **certain** machines?

Might it have something to do with the fact that these `Color` objects are defined in Spring like this:

```
<bean id="sludge" class="java.awt.Color">
    <constructor-arg value="133"/>
    <constructor-arg value="133"/>
    <constructor-arg value="78"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: I just tried both the java-only as well as the spring version, and both work for me. I notice that you're exception message is incomplete, there should be something after "expected range". What version of java are you using?

Comment: @skaffman, I'll edit the question to complete the message.

Comment: The IAE can be thrown either on testing int or float values. Can you debug and catch the exception (or look at the stacktrace) whether it's the testColorValueRange(int,int,int,int) or the testColorValueRange(float,float,float,float) method that throws the IAE? Although I'm pretty sure, that the 'float-type' constructor is used to create the Color. Do all machines use the same Java version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm NOT an expert with spring. but did you tried to set the **type** to **int** ?

```
<constructor-arg type="int" value="133">
```

?

Comment: +1 Not sure if that'll make a difference, but I like the way you're thinking

Comment: And did you try to add a <value/> tag ? <constructor-arg type="int"><value>133</value></constructor-arg> ?

Comment: @Pierre - I was being a spoon; your first suggestion did the business

Comment: @Paul McKenzie - but Spring uses precedence in a sorted list of valid constructors, and both the int and float constructors are valid based upon the call in my q. How would it know to pick the right one without a nudge?

Answer (score 4):

being more pedant:

```
<bean id="sludge" class="java.awt.Color">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="int"><value>133</value></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1" type="int"><value>133</value></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2" type="int"><value>78</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

**EDIT**

check also [this blog post](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2009/02/jdk6-spring-20-adventure/)